# копирование кода xaml в usercontrol c#

Tags: wpf, uwp, usercontrol

добрый день. каким образом можно программно копировать datatemplate из ресурсов приложения и вставить в собственный usercontrol?

Comment: Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V пробовали?

Comment: вы, видимо, не поняли. необходимо на основании данных программно скопировать уже заготовленный шаблон из ресурсов в свой юзерконтрол. 
данные каждый раз разные

Comment: А зачем копировать то, подключаете ресурсы и пользуетесь. По имени или типу данных.

Comment: А данные того же типа, для которого UserControl?

Answer (score 2):

Рискну предположить, что ваши данные приходят из привязки и находятся в `DataContext`'е. Для этого случая работает просто

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding тут-ваша-привязка}"/>
```

Убедитесь, что ресурсы из `ResourceDictionary` подключены, чтобы `DataTemplate` был виден.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51949/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---xaml--usercontrol-c).